# Why use this 2 DFF method every time a button press is involved?

Tags: verilog, fpga

I have been reading verilog code online and have noticed this in many of the code examples. Whenever an input is needed from a hardware source such as a button press, the input is copied to a flip flop and then AND'd with the invert of the input. I dont know if this made much sense but in code here it is:

```
input btn;
reg dff1, dff2;
wire db_tick;

always @ (posedge clock) dff1 <= btn;
always @ (posedge clock) dff2 <= dff1;

assign db_tick = ~dff1 & dff2;
```

And then `db_tick` is used as the button press.

In some cases this is also used as a rising edge detector, but cant a rising edge detector easily be implemented with `always@(posedge signal)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a *monostable multivibrator* or, specifically for digital circuits, a one-shot. The purpose of the circuit is to change an edge into a single cycle pulse.

When connected directly to a physical switch it can be a way to effect switch debouncing, but that's not really a good use for it. It's hard to say what the intent is in the code without more context.

Comment: can you please explain why one has to be inverted and AND ed to the other?

Comment: Regarding the inversion: the output is a single pulse of the clock instead of a constant high while the button is pressed. It's good for resets and state machines that expect a pulse rather than a constant high.

Comment: Surely you need quite a slow clock for this to work for debouncing?  switches bounces for some milliseconds usually...

Comment: @MartinThompson I used it and its does work on my board as a debouncer. I have a 50 MHz clock

Comment: @saardrimer thanks for the explanation. Now suppose if it was ``db_tick = dff1 & ~dff2;`` would it be detecting the negative edge? Or positive edge?

Comment: @ipunished: You may have gotten lucky then... I wouldn't use anything as fast as 40ns for switch debouncing personally!

Comment: @MartinThompson I see it commonly misused for debouncing since it can be deceptively effective.

Answer (score 2):

This is providing edge detection synchronous to your clock domain. I do not see any debouncing happing here, it is quite common to also include 2 meta stability flip flops before the edge detection.

```
input a;

reg [2:0] a_meta;
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    a_meta <= 3'b0 ;
  end
  else begin
    a_meta <= {a_meta[1:0], a};
  end
end

// The following signals will be 1 clk wide, Clock must be faster than event rate.
// a[2] is the oldest data,
//   if new data (a[1]) is high and old data low we have just seen a rising edge.
wire a_sync_posedge = ~a_meta[2] &  a_meta[1];
wire a_sync_negedge =  a_meta[2] & ~a_meta[1]; 
wire a_sync_anyedge =  a_meta[2] ^  a_meta[1]; //XOR
```

Comment: I agree, it looks like synchronisation + edge detect.  No debouncing I can see either

Comment: Is the fifth line `if (~rst_n) begin` supposed to be `if (rst_n) begin` ??

Comment: @krismath, no, it is negedge (active low) triggered reset. So reset condition is active when reset is 0.